# Tell if a set $K \subseteq\mathbb R $, closed in $\tau_d$ and bounded by the distance d is necessarily compact in $\tau_d$

Tags: general-topology, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Considering the following metric over $\mathbb R$:

$d(x,y)=|x-y|/(1+|x-y|)$

I have to

1) find if ($\mathbb R$,d) is a complete metric space

2)Tell if a set $K  \subseteq\mathbb R   $,  closed in  $\tau_d$ and bounded by $d$ is necessarily compact in $\tau_d$

So I already proved part 1: I took a Cauchy sequence with respect to d and proved that the completeness of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology implies the sequence is convergent and therefore $(\mathbb R,d)$ is a complete metric space .
How do I proceed with part 2 ?

Note: the answer is No!, but I'd like to know why

Comment: If $e$ is a metric on a set $S$ and $d(x,y)=e(x,y)/(1+e(x,y))$ then $d$ generates the same topology that $e$ does. Compactness of a subset depends only on the topology.  Every  set is bounded with respect to $d.$ In your Q, $\Bbb R$ is closed and $d$-bounded but not compact.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  How can I see the topology is the same?

Answer (score 1):

If $B_d(x_0,\epsilon )$ is the ball that it's center is $x_0$ and it's radius is $\epsilon $  with the metric $d$. then

$$B_d(x_0,\epsilon )=\{ x: d(x,x_0)<\epsilon\}=\{x: \frac{|x-x_0|}{1+|x-x_0|}<\epsilon \}=\{x: 1+|x-x_0|<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon } \}=\{ 
 x: |x-x_0|<\frac{\epsilon }{1-\epsilon} \}=B(x_0, \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}) $$

So every open set in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The proof is only valid for $\epsilon<1$, isn't this a problem?... so, does this prove this metric generates the same topology? and how do you prove every bounded set in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is also bounded on $ \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $\epsilon \geq1$ then $B_d(x_0,\epsilon )=\mathbb{R}$ that is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Every bounded set in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is in a ball in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ and every ball in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}$. So every bounded set in $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It is not necessary to prove that two topologies are equal. It is enough to prove that $\tau_d\subseteq \tau$, and I proved it in the above

Comment: So the answer to the question " a set $K  \subseteq\mathbb R   $,  closed in  $\tau_d$ and bounded by $d$ is necessarily compact in $\tau_d$".... is yes?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver. NO. $\Bbb R$ is closed and bounded by $d$ and $not$ compact..... EVERY subset of $\Bbb R$ is bounded by $d$ because $d(x,y)<1$ for all $x,y.$

Comment: You wrote :"So if a set $K$ is closed and bounded in $(\mathbb{R},d)$, it is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ too. So it is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ So is compact in $(\mathbb{R},d)$."  I don't see why you conclude the last implication, how do you go from being compact in $\mathbb{R}$  to being compact in $(\mathbb{R},d)$  and how does this answer the question?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  To answer the question with a no, we need to show that a closed and bounded set in the new metric space can be non-compact. The question is abount a subset, not about the whole space

Comment: "Subset" does not mean proper subset. Anyway, since $d$ and the metric $e(x,y)=|x-y|$ generate the  same topology, an example is $\Bbb N,$ which is bounded with respect to $d,$ and closed, but not compact.